# initializing matlab dlls and calling an inc function from Delphi XE

Tags: matlab, delphi

I'm trying to call a simple Matlab routine, from a Delphi XE 32bit application, which I have compiled into a shared C libray called Test.dll using the Matlab 2012b compiler.
The routine increments a number and returns the new value.

As I understand from the matlab documentation I first need to call mclInitializeApplication.
I've mapped this dll call as follows:

```
unit mclmcrWrapper;

interface

type
  TAnsiArray = TArray<AnsiString>;
  PAnsiArray = ^TAnsiArray;

  function mclInitializeApplication(A: PAnsiArray; B: Integer): Boolean; cdecl; external 'mclmcr.dll' name '_mclInitializeApplication'; 

  // Also tried, with same result:
  // All attempts made with and without underscore give the same results.
  // function mclInitializeApplication(A: PAnsiArray; B: Integer): Boolean; cdecl; external 'mclmcr.dll' name '_mclInitializeApplication'; 
  // function mclInitializeApplication(A: THandle; B: Integer): Boolean; cdecl; external 'mclmcr.dll' name '_mclInitializeApplication'; 

implementation

initialization
  mclInitializeApplication(nil, 0); //Initialize the matlab runtime
end.
```

According to ddlDepends the function is present in the dll.
When I execute my program I get the following error message:

```
---------------------------
MatlabTest.exe - Entry Point Not Found
---------------------------
The procedure entry point _mclInitializeApplication could not be located in the dynamic link library mclmcr.dll. 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

All dll's are present in the same folder. If they are not I get an error that the dll itself cannot be found.
In itself this is also strange as the Matlab compiled runtime is installed on my system, and it is added to the windows path correctly.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure about the underscore in the function name ? For instance in [`this answer`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99056-how-do-i-use-the-mclinitializeapplication-function-to-make-a-c-shared-library-that-does-not-use-the) there is no underscore in its name. And it's quite recent post from the vendor support team.

Comment: Actually, no I'm not sure, although the underscore is often required. I also tried without an underscore, which gave me the same results. I've update this in the post.

Comment: Some name decoration schemes include an underscore. In this case, depends tells you that there is no underscore. So don't include it. Then when you do so, the system tells you that *mclInitializeApplication could not be located in the dynamic link library mclmcr.dll*. Well, trust the system. It is correct. There is no such function in that DLL. It's in a different DLL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far as I know, that function is actually defined in `mclbase.dll`.

Once you resolve the linking, I suggest that you change the parameter list for your imported function. It's risky to pass Delphi managed types to a non-Delphi module. I would declare it like this:

```
type
  PPAnsiChar = ^PAnsiChar;

function mclInitializeApplication(A: PPAnsiChar; B: Integer): Boolean; cdecl;
  external 'mclbase.dll';
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had a couple of things to fix:

1. Install the MCR correctly.
2. Pass a `PPAnsiChar` instead of an array
3. Call "_proxy" functions in mclmcrrt8_0.dll, instead of the normal functions in the other dll files.

The method declaration is now as follows:

```
function DLLInit(A: PPAnsiChar; B: integer): Boolean; cdecl;
  external 'mclmcrrt8_0.dll' name 'mclInitializeApplication_proxy';
```

in the unit I added the following code (yes, I'm not passing any parameters):

```
initialization

if not DLLInit(@MyString, 0) then
  raise Exception.Create('Could not initialize Matlab library.');
```

I also made sure that this unit is the first to be loaded in the project, as the `mclInitializeApplication` needs to be called once and before all other matlab calls.

Comment: @David, I apologize for that.I am always grateful for the help I receive on stackoverflow from people like you. When I initially accepted your answer it seemed to be working and I therefore accepted it as the correct answer. I agree that installing the MCR does not directly relate to the answer and you were correct in the parameter declaration, however the most important error I had made was that I did not use mclmcrrt8_0.dll.

Comment: @David, part 2: As you can guess by my reputation I'm not too familiar with stackoverflow yet, so I thought I was doing the right thing in answering my own question. Should I have left yours as the accepted answer instead or should I have not answered my question at all? when I read the help popup when you start answering your own question, it seemed like I was doing the correct thing.

Comment: It's absolutely fine to answer your own question. The thing is though, you did not do that. What you wrote was a lot of detail about things that only you can see that were not included in the question. As such it is only of interest to you. SO follows quite a strict question and answer policy.

Comment: I'll write an answer to your other Q soon

Comment: David, I understand your reaction. It made me think about what the rules for answering your own question are and indeed your answer helped me out. I accepted it again to reflect that. My question was what I was doing wrong in order to initialize the MCR correctly. Maybe this was not clear in my question (nor in my answer). Is it OK for me to update both to make this more clear? Please do help me with my other problem.