# What needs to be done to use a matlab DLL in Delphi

Tags: matlab, delphi, dll

I am working on a project where I am being given a DLL, which had been created in matlab, its source is a matlab .m file. I understand that to be able to use the matlab .ddl's I need to have installed the matlab runtime complier. I have done this.

It's the next steps that I need to know about.

From reading another article on here I can see that first I need to initialise the runtime and then to initialise each DLL. I am unsure of the proper way to do any of this. I have made a new unit but I am unsure how to go about completing it so I can use the functions included within the DLL's.

The unit Code is as follows:

```
unit MatLabIF;

interface

type

    PPAnsiChar = ^PAnsiChar;

    function mclInitializeApplication(A: PAnsiChar; B: Integer): Boolean; cdecl;
    external 'mclbase.dll';

    procedure openMCL;

implementation

uses

Windows,sysUtils,MMSystem,Classes,Dialogs,QuickUSB,Math,StirScanDemoApp;

{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}

procedure openMCL;

begin

    if not(mclInitializeApplication(nil,0)) then showMessage('App failed to open')
    else showMessage('App Opened Correctly')
end;
 {------------------------------------------------------------------------------}

end.
```

When I tried to run the code I got the error message that "mclbase.dll is missing from your computer", I went into the matlab runtime complier folder, found the missing mclbase.dll and copied it into the project folder.

The next time I tried to run the program another dll was missing, is this going to keep happening? How can I tell delphi to look in the matlab folder to find all the dll's it needs? Do I need some sort of statment in the "uses" section like "mcl" ????

In short,

How to I use a matlab dll in delphi using the matlab runtime complier?

Comment: You could add the directory that contains the matlab DLLs to your systems PATH environment variable.

Comment: I feel as if there should be an entry in the "uses" section of the unit code.

Comment: Don't get confused between Delphi `uses` directive and DLL search path. These things could not be less related.

Comment: You should also avoid using meaningless parameter names. What made you choose `A` and `B`? The function is `bool mclInitializeApplication(const char **options, int count);`. One consequence is that the first parameter should be `PPAnsiChar` in your Delphi code.

Comment: The reason I felt that they were related was that, for example, the "QuickUSB" entry in the uses section allows me to call functions from the QuickUSB library. Would you be able to explain the difference?

Comment: I was copying the answer you gave in a previous question. I assumed that was how this should be laid out.

Comment: Ha! I was copying the code in the question there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21402748/initializing-matlab-dlls-and-calling-an-inc-function-from-delphi-xe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the DLL search path to be able to find the MATLAB runtime. Some ways of achieving that:

1. Add the MATLAB runtime folder to the system path. This is a grossly heavy handed approach that is generally to be avoided. For your personal use it is the most convenient.
2. Use `SetDllDirectory` or `AddDllDirectory` to extend the search path.

Option 2 is only possible if you can call these functions before the loader attempts to load the DLL. That's not possible for load time linking. You can deal with that using one of the following techniques:

- Move your code into a separate module, and call one of these functions from the host.
- Switch to run time linking with `LoadLibrary`.
- Use delay load linking with the `delayed` directive.

Note that the choice of variable names `A` and `B` is poor. Don't make the code hard to follow.  What's more, the first parameter to that function is a pointer to pointer to null terminated string. It's an array of strings. Use `PPAnsiChar`.

Comment: I don't think I am using load time linking, although I am not totally sure what that means, do you mead loading the dll as soon as the application starts? Because I am not doing that, I can open the matlab runtime when ever I want, the application is not dependant on it.

Comment: You are using load time linking. That's what you get with the `external` directive. Unless you add `delayed`. It's easy to find out what load time linking is if you are not sure. You simply have to type it into a web search engine.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer David, I think I going to have to learn a lot to get this to work. Out of interest, if I do decide to add the matlab runtime folder to the system path, what does this entail, putting the folder in the project directory?

Comment: No, you don't move any files. You modify the system environment variable named `PATH`. The shell provides a UI for setting env vars, but I do that using a tool named Rapid Environment Editor.

Comment: Ok, I have found what I need, do I add just the top level directory for the matlab runtime complier? Will it know how to look down the file system to find what it needs?

Comment: You need to add the directory that contains the dll you use. DLL search is a delicate business. The system certainly will not go hunting around for other directories. It looks where it is told. No more, no less.

Comment: Hmmm, what's odd is that the folder I need is already there... So why isn't delphi finding it?

Comment: You are probably confused over something. Perhaps Delphi was running before the environment variable was changed. Did you restart Delphi?

Comment: In my "path" box I already have "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v715\runtime\win32; As well as many other things..

Comment: I will try that, is there any reason delphi would be unable to access the system path?

Comment: Why is the PATH in quotes? Anyway, if the DLL is in the PATH of the process, you won't get that error. So keep digging around.

Comment: There is no reason why Delphi cannot access the system PATH. But a process gets its environment when it starts. I suggest that you learn about environment variables too.

Comment: I found the problem, although there was an entry for "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v715\runtime\win32" The DLL's needed are actually located in "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v715\bin\win32" Changing that seems to make it work, although I'm sure there will be other dangers lurking!